# JTextFiled not updating when edited in a while loop

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jtextfield

**I want the JTextFiled to go up quickly as if it were a clock**

the following code is inside a mouse listener.
Also t1 IS public and was declared before the main method in the class.
If you any questions pleas tell me!
ddd = 1. The rest of the switch statement is the same just instead of t1 its t2 or t3 or t4...

```
        try {
                String rol = null;
            String har = null;
            int rolx = 0;
            int harx = 0;
            int newl = 0;
        switch (ddd) {
        case 1:
            rol = t1.getText();
            har = numb.getText();
            rolx = Integer.parseInt(rol);
            harx = Integer.parseInt(har);
            newl = rolx + harx;
            while (harx > 0) {
                harx --;
                rolx ++;
                Thread.sleep(10);
                System.out.println(""+rolx);
                t1.setText(""+rolx);
            }
            t1.setText(""+newl);

            break;
```

Comment: See Patricia's answer; you should look into [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), although I've never used this particular class and I'm sure it's not the only way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do directly inside a Listener's event handling code holds the event handling thread, preventing any GUI activity.

You need to either move the loop to another thread, or use some form of timer instead.

Comment: So basicially don't invoke Thread.sleep(). Instead us a Swing Timer.

Comment: You don't understand. I know the timer works I used System.out.println but my problem is after the while loop I can set t1 to newl but inside it I cant do anything!

Comment: That is because the while loop is running in the event handling thread. Other events, such as updates to the display, are getting queued up and can happen once the method returns. You need to either get that loop completely out into another thread, or break it up by setting a timer and returning immediately.